# Google Maps API - Multiple keywords in place searches

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible search multiple individual keywords in one place search request using Google Maps JavaScript API v3?

In the Google Places API documentation it states that multiple keywords can be used https://developers.google.com/places/training/additional-places-features

`?keyword=theater+gym`

but this does not work in the JavaScript API. I tried:

```
function performSearch() {
  var request = {
    location: map.center,
    radius: '500',
    keyword: 'theater+gym+tacos',
    rankBy: 'distance'
  };
  service.radarSearch(request, callback);
}
```

...and does not return places for each keyword. Does anyone have an idea how to search multiple keywords?

**Note:** I'm trying to search multiple individual keywords in one request not a phrase with spaces.

Comment: Did you try using a space instead of the "+"? or a space with the +?

Comment: yes i tried both. they both return less results and usually biased to one keyword.

Comment: have you tried `%20` instead?

Comment: @duncan using that symbol doesn't work neither :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like the answer is "no" (at least at the present time, you could request an [enhancement on the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/).

A work around would be to send three separate queries, one for each keyword.  Should be OK for 3 keywords, at some point you will run into the query rate limit.

```
  var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: 500,
    keyword: 'theater'
  };
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
  var request2 = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: 500,
    keyword: 'gym'
  };
  var service2 = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service2.nearbySearch(request2, callback);
  var request3 = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: 500,
    keyword: 'tacos'
  };
  var service3 = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service3.nearbySearch(request2, callback);
```

[proof of concept](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_place-search_keyword3.html)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var infowindow;

function initialize() {
  var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433, 151.1956316);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: pyrmont,
    zoom: 15
  });

  var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: 500,
    keyword: 'theater'
  };
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
  var request2 = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: 500,
    keyword: 'gym'
  };
  var service2 = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service2.nearbySearch(request2, callback);
  var request3 = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: 500,
    keyword: 'tacos'
  };
  var service3 = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service3.nearbySearch(request2, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  } else alert("Places request failed: " + status);
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Using Google place API, Make a boolean search seems to work like this :

```
var request = {
            location: /*your location*/,
            radius: /*your radius*/,              
            keyword: "(cinema) OR (theater)"           
        };
```

you can use OR, AND but respect case!!

Comment: This does not work. Some link to documentation would be helpful.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Is there documentation on this anywhere?

Comment: Is  there a documentation for this. Did anyone achieved this with or conditions?

Comment: Fantastic! tested and seems to work... mate you just saved my client x8 requests... world is a better place now....

Comment: This does not work all the time, and there is no documentation, I'd say this only worked for you out of coincidence.

Comment: Worked for me too. Should be marked as the right answer

Comment: The documentation does actually state that keywords are an optional parameter that can be passed, but they don't provide a working example as far as I could find. This was a lifesaver and worked great.

Comment: Capital OR was a factor for me. Also, utilizing single quotes appears to work.  E.g.:  keyword="'cinema' OR 'theater'"

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem as I tried to figure out how to use multiple keywords with one request. At first the answer of @netoale helped me, but this is no longer possible. After some general problems with Google I asked in the support and one of the employees wrote me that it is possible to link several keywords with a simple "|".

As an example:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=lat,lng&key=API_KEY&keyword=theater|castle|park&rankby=distance
```

Works for me now.

Comment: While this may work, this is not officially supported in the Nearby Search documentation (https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) and might stop working. Also with this solution you might not get enough results for each type you are trying to query.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: This appeared to work initially but more results were not reliable and were not predictable. We ended up not being able to use the API in this way for our scenario.

I use the web service but I assume it should work with all API access points. It took me quite a number combinations to test but I eventually landed on realizing the API required parentheses AND quotes to get multi-word OR conditions to work.

For example, in url param form:

keywords=("Place Name 1") OR ("PlaceName2") OR ("Place Name3")

Comment: Can you please provide Js fiddle for this example. It would be of great help

Comment: Yep, doesn't really work reliably or predictably. I edited the answer.

Comment: Utilizing single quotes, without ( ), appears to work consistently.
 Mar. 2022 E.g.: keyword="'cinema' OR 'theater'"

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with type option. If using type you can get more than one place information

Please see the possible [supported types](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#RadarSearchRequests) and [RadarSearchRequests](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#RadarSearchRequests)
try like this

```
function performSearch() {
  var request = {
    location: map.center,
    radius: '500',
    types: ['movie_theater', 'gym'],
    rankBy: 'distance'
  };
  service.radarSearch(request, callback);
}
```

I don't know 'tacos' is which type. please supported type and give that 'tacos' type value.

Please let me know if you have any issues

Comment: Thanks, type accepts multiple values but I'm trying to achieve that with keywords.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is related to [Google Maps API open issue 4845](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4845). Please star that issue to track progress.

Comment: That issue deals with spaces for phrases, My question of for multiple individual keywords.