# Google nearby search with multiple keywords

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-places-api

Im trying to fetch both restaurants and cafes from googles Places API using the nearby search query.

Excerpt from my query string:

```
...&radius=2000&keyword=cafe+restaurant&key=myAPIKey
```

Using the plus '+' seems to bias towards one keyword type and returns a very limited quantity of places (limited versus using i.e. the restaurant and the cafe keywords on separate queries).

I've also tried using single pipe, %20, double pipe to name a few but nothing seems to work.

I've looked at this SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625228/google-maps-api-multiple-keywords-in-place-searches), the solution here (its 7 years old now) uses a workaround making two separate calls which I was hoping has now been resolved within the query string?

Is it possible to query nearby search for two keywords i.e. cafe and restaurant using a single query string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible. You need to make multiple requests to the API for this, one with `keyword=cafe` or `type=cafe`, and the other with `keyword=restaurant` or `type=restaurant`.

You may also want to file a feature request for this in Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188872&template=789309).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Evan, was thinking this was the case.